# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It's a question from Artin's Algebra.
The ordinary question is to verify $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$, my answer is $\mathbb{F}_2[i]$.

My way is:
Firstly, figure out that the ideal is equal to $(x^2+2x+1,2)$, then we can compute $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)$ and it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ then we can compute $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+2x+1) = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2[i]$.

Am I wrong or right? If I am wrong, then what's the right answer and where did I make mistake?

Comment: How did you get that the ideal is the same as $(x^2+2x+1,2)$? This is not trivial. I can see that $x^2+2x+1=(x^2-3)+(2x+4)$, but how did you get $2$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb F_2[i]$, since $x^2+1$ already has a root in $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: @lhf Oh I made the mistake here, then how to solve this problem?

Comment: Now I see, using long division you got $$2= 2(x^2-3)-(2x-1)(2x+4))$$. As lhf says, this ring is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_2 [x]/(x^2+1) \cong \Bbb F_2 \times \Bbb F_2$

Comment: @Crostul Since $4 = 2(x^2 - 3) + x(2x + 4) + 2x + 4$

Comment: @Crostul How does the isomorphism come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no $i$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Since $(x^2-3)+(2x+4)=x^2+2x+1$ and $2(x^2-3)-(x-2)(2x+4)=2$, the inclusion
$$
(x^2+2x+1,2)\subseteq(x^2-3,2x+4)
$$
holds. The reverse inclusion can be proved similarly.

By the homomorphism theorems,
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+2x+1,2)\cong
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)}{(x^2+2x+1,2)/(2)}
\cong\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+2x+1)
$$
which is not a field, because $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$ is not irreducible.

One can say that this ring is $\mathbb{F}_2[u]$, where $(u+1)^2=0$. This is the same as requiring $u^2=1$. The ring consists of the elements
$$
a+bu
$$
with $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_2$, componentwise addition and multiplication
$$
(a+bu)(c+du)=(ac+bd)+(ad+bc)u
$$

Comment: But $2x$ is zero in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$? How does it exist to be the ideal?

Comment: @R.Sherlock Where's the problem? In $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ exactly because $2x=0$.

Comment: So in fact the element $u$ satisfies $u^2 + 1 = 0$?

Comment: @R.Sherlock Exactly, or $u^2=1$, which is the same. The element $1+u$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: But ... this u is just a form, since it's hard to show what the u exactly is, or, it's just a way to extend a ring? Can you recommend some books?

Comment: @R.Sherlock It's just a new element, actually the image of $x$ in the canonical homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_2[x]\to\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: But if we adjoin $u$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$, is that isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2[i]$ ?

Comment: @R.Sherlock What's $i$?

Comment: $i$ is the imaginary number $i$

Comment: @R.Sherlock Does it belong to the two element field or any of its extension fields?

Comment: No, but I think there exists isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_2[i]$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ since $i$ satisfies $i^2 = -1 = 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: @R.Sherlock NO complex number belongs to ANY extension field of the two element field, which *cannot* be embedded in the complex numbers to begin with.

Comment: Oh I firstly hear that, can you give me more details? Thanks!